# Not able to navigate through different sections of administrator page of fresh installed drupal 7.14

Tags: installation

At the first instance after finishing installation the link "Go to your new website" directs to the parent directory.
Then I tried with appending "index.php" to "http://localhost/drupal/" it displayed admin home but now Clicking on any link displays the root directory of drupal site.
I am not able to navigate through different sections of administrator page of drupal.

Answer (score 1):

During drupal installation you should be careful of following things;

1. Download and unzip drupal properly.
2. copy and paste that into your var/www (for linux) and xampp/htdocs (windows).
3. Rename the drupal folder to ur project name. Don't make any subfolder.
4. Make sure there is no spaces during renaming the drupal folder.
5. After creating database. Doing changes in settings.php run install.php in ur browser.
6. If u r using linux give all permissions.

Comment: Thanks for reply Rishi.
I got the problem it was problem with DirectoryIndex directive in httpd.conf file.
Added index.php there..
and now its working fine..